# Powershell Read Azure VM from Resourcegroup and increment create new one

Tags: virtual-machine, azure-powershell

When i get all vm's from a resourcegroup. I have a list with results

### Name

VM-XXXXX-BB-6
VM-XXXXX-BB-7

How can i create two new vm's and go up or down by one number.

Comment: Can you explain clearly, what are you trying and what you want to do?

Comment: Im searching for a script that will create two other machines with VM-XXXXX-8 and 9. But constantly checks what number of VM already is in use by name.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i create two new vm's and go up or down by one number.

I have used below powershell script to create new **VM** by going up in one number.

```
connect-AzAccount
$rgName = "venkat-v"
$vm_names = (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName).Name
foreach ($name in $vm_names) {
    $last_digits = $name -replace '^.*(\d+)$', '$1'
    Write-Host $last_digits
}

$LargeNumber = ($last_digits | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
Write-Host $LargeNumber
$adminUsername = "Venkat"
$adminPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Welcome@123$" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($adminUsername, $adminPassword)
$vmParams = @{
  ResourceGroupName = 'venkat-v'
  Name = "VM$($largest_number+1)"
  Location = 'eastus'
  ImageName = 'Win2016Datacenter'
  PublicIpAddressName = 'mypublicip'
  Credential = $credential
  OpenPorts = 3389
  Size = 'Standard_D2s_v3'
}
$newVM1 = New-AzVM @vmParams
```

**Output:**

[image]

Once ran the above PowerShell script **VM 8** got created successfully.

[image]

Similarly, you can create another **VM** by changing the VM name **VM$($largest_number+2)**